# Unable to include/require PHP file

Tags: php, netbeans, path, include

I'm making a simple application for managing the employees' tasks, called WorkerManager. At first, I had the following structure:

```
workermanager
|-index.php
|
|-user
|   |-dao
|   |  |-UserDAO.php
|   |-model
|   |-view
|-task
|   |-dao
|   |-model
|   |-view
|-department
|   |-dao
|   |-model
|   |-view
...
```

So, UserDAO.php was located in `workermanager/user/dao/` and I was including it using `require_once './user/dao/UserDAO.php'`.

Later on, I decided to change the structure of the project and made something like this:

```
workermanager
|-index.php
|
|-dao
|   |-user
|   |   |-UserDAO.php
|   |-task
|   |-department
|-model
|   |-user
|   |-task
|   |-department
|-view
|   |-user
|   |-task
|   |-department
...
```

I did this by creating folders, dragging & dropping inside the NetBeans Projects pane. Since then, I'm unable to include `UserDAO.php` (or any other file that changed the location). The function `file_exists('./dao/user/UserDAO.php')` returns false. When I `echo` the file location using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/workermanager/dao/user/UserDAO.php'`, it gives the correct path, but when I try to `include` or `require` it this way, it doesn't work. I have tried to erase this project and to make a new one with existing sources, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what can I do?

Next time when I decide to change the tree structure, should I do it outside the NetBeans? Is there any way to make the NetBeans "scan" the project structure and to "learn" new paths?

I'm using NetBeans 8.1, Apache 2.4.18, Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks.

**Edit**:
Slightly off-topic... In a project like this, if I have one "model", one "DAO" and one or more "view" files for each entity, what structure do you prefer? Are there any "best practices" regarding the project tree shape?

**Edit 2**:
I've just made a new project with the following structure:

```
shoppinglist
|-index.php
|...
|-list
|   |-ShoppingList.php
|   |-ShoppingListController.php
|   |-create-new-list.php
|   |-edit-list.php
|...
...
```

In `index.php` I have `require_once './list/ShoppingListController.php';` and it works perfectly. But in `list/edit-list.php` I have exactly the same line and it doesn't work. I have also tried to require/include only `'ShoppingListController.php'`, as well as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shoppinglist/list/ShoppingListController.php'`, but still nothing. Can anyone tell me what is going on???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution!

In every `include` or `require` I have started the path with `'./'`. I thought it was the root of my site, but it's the current folder. So, it was fine to use `'./list/ShoppingListController.php'` in `index.php`, but it shouldn't be used in `edit-list.php`, which is located in the same folder as `ShoppingListController.php`.

The solution was to use `dirname(__FILE__)` at the beginning of each `include` or `require` and then to concatenate the rest of the path.

For example, in `index.php` I have:

`require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/list/ShoppingListController.php';`

...while in `edit-list.php` I have:

`require dirname(__FILE__).'/ShoppingListController.php';`

In `ShoppingListController.php` I need to include several files, so I have:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../db/DBConnection.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/ShoppingList.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../article/Article.php';
```

That solved my problem and now everything works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Apache cached your index.php file, and still uses the old paths. You should check that.

Netbeans is just an IDE that changes your files. There is no way Netbeans is problem here, you could as well use Notepad to change these paths, that would be the same from the project perspective.

Comment: How can I clear the cache? I've checked /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk, and it's empty. Is there any other place to look at? I've been googling for hours but I'm unable to find out how to clean the cache...